# Why method in python dosen't work, but code beyod method works?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to process a table, I wrote a code to delete rows where in `'A1_TOP'` col or in '`A2_TOP'` col is `-`.

code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('SomeFile.txt')
df = df.loc[(df['A1_TOP'] != gap) | (df['A2_TOP'] != gap)]
```

And it's work fine when I put it into code. From data frame the rows with the value '-' disappear. But I tried to create a method, coz I using this code some time, DRY u know... :) and when I put it to the method and tried to use it, I got no errors, just a dataframe without deleting rows. There are still gaps.

This is how the method is called:

```
#Load file
df = pd.read_csv('SomeFile.txt')

#creating method
def delete_gaps(df):
    df = df.loc[(df['A1_TOP'] != gap) | (df['A2_TOP'] != gap)]
    #df = df.loc[(df['A1_TOP'] != gapVariant) | (df['A2_TOP'] != gapVariant)]
    return df

#method call
delete_gaps(df)
```

I suspect then I doing something wrong with parameters? Or perhaps with calling? I tried `df = delete_gaps(df)`, but then obviously got empty df.

If someone can explain to me what is a problem, and why is it, I will be grateful.

P.S. I didn't put the table in question, coz i think it's not a problem. Code beyond method works fine.

Comment: What is `a`? And redefining `df` inside the function won't reflect that outside the function; `return` the new value instead.

Comment: probably you need to do `return df`

Comment: Sorry, "a" its df. Edited. I added `return df` to the method but still have the same result; C

Comment: And I hope you have destroyed the kernel,,restarted it again and then tried!! Bcoz sometimes method doesn't change!!

Comment: yes, I restarted kernel and rerun, but still have gaps in df after called method. If I run exactly the same code beyond method - works.

Comment: And why I got minuses? :> Something is wrong with question?

Comment: Add this as your 1st line in the function and then let me know `df = df.copy(deep=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this in your method :

```
def delete_gaps(df):
    df = df.copy(deep=True)
    df = df.loc[(df['A1_TOP'] != gap) | (df['A2_TOP'] != gap)]

    return df
```

If you pass the dataframe into a function and manipulate it and return the same dataframe, you are going to get the same dataframe in modified version.If you don't want to change the original dataframe your best bet is to make a copy of the original dataframe.

I used the copy method and the argument "deep=True" makes a copy of the dataframe and its contents.

You can read more here:http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html